# What is an unit area vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, physics, area, electromagnetism

As the title suggests,

> What is a unit area vector?

I've tried googling but unable to arrive at any satisfactory answers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Context it appeared in? Off the top of my head, the only thing I can think of (based on the tags) would be the unit normal vector to a surface with an area element "attached" to it.

Comment: Electromagnetism.
There is a bound surface current $\vec{K}_{b}$passing through an amperian loop of length L of area a.
The total current is then 
$\vec{K}_{b}L.\hat{a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the surface $S$ defined by the Ampèrian loop $\partial S$. Then, a vector normal to this surface and with magnitude equal to the area of the surface is $\vec a$. This is commonly referred to as the *vector area* of $S$. Then, the unit vector $\hat a$ is a vector parallel to $\vec a$, but with unit length.

The total current flowing through $S$ is proportional to the integral of the current density $\vec j$ over $S$:

$$
\iint_{S}\vec j\cdot d\vec a = \iint_S \vec j\cdot \hat a\,da.
$$

Generally, to determine the orientation of $\hat a$ at a point on a surface $S$, we have to parametrize $S$. For example, our surface may be defined on an open region $D$ as $S(s,t) = (x(s,t), y(s,t), z(s,t))$. For curved surfaces, the vector $\hat a$ is a function of $s$ and $t$. Using properties of the cross product, we calculate $S_s$ and $S_t$, and evaluate the cross product at a point $(S_s\times S_t)(s_0,t_0)$, to determine $\vec a(s_0,t_0)$. Determining $\hat a$ is a matter of dividing out the length. Thus, in general we have the formula for a vector surface integral of a vector field $\vec F$ over a parametrized surface $S: D\to \Bbb R^3$:
$$
\iint_S \vec F\cdot d\vec a=\iint_D\vec F(\vec r(s,t))\cdot\hat a(s,t)\,ds\,dt = \iint_D\vec F(\vec r(s,t))\cdot\frac{S_s(s,t)\times S_t(s,t)}{\Vert S_s(s,t)\times S_t(s,t)\Vert}\,ds\,dt.$$

Comment: What does $\vec{J}.\hat{a}$ tells us? Sure I know it is the dot product but what does it tells us physically?

Comment: @Mathematicing, good question. There is a good physical interpretation of this. In general, the dot product measures how much two vectors "align" with each other. So if $\vec j\cdot\hat a$ is positive, we have a net flow of current density through the surface $S$ in the direction of $\hat a$. Similarly, if $\vec j\cdot\hat a$ is negative, we have a net flow of current density through the surface $S$ in the opposite direction of $\hat a$. If $\vec j\cdot\hat a$ is zero, there is no net flow of current density through the surface $S$ in the direction of $\hat a$.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is a good way to determine the direction of the vector $\hat{a}$?

Comment: @Mathematicing, we generally choose our Ampèrian loops with orientation,   say counterclockwise when looking down from the positive $z$-axis. Then, the area vector will have the same direction that your thumb does when your right hand fingers curl in the direction of the loop. In the case of a loop that is counterclockwise when looking down from the positive $z$-axis, the direction of $\hat a$ would be the same as $hat z$.

Comment: @Mathematicing, Also see my updated answer for how to determine the orientation of $\hat a$ for more general surfaces.

Comment: I've seen that before and my multivariate calculus has certainly gotten rusty after last touching it two years ago.
I was wondering if it is possible to deduce the direction via physical reasoning?
Would it help if I told you that a circular Amperian loop is centered at the axis of symmetry(the symmetry is the z-axis) of a cylinder with volume current moving through the loop in the positive direction and surface current moving in the -z direction along the boundary of the cylinder?

Comment: @Mathematicing, In general, it is a good idea to choose the orientation of our Ampèrian loop to be the same as the magnetic field induced by the current through our loop. In this case, since your loop encloses a current density that moves in the $+\hat z$ direction, it would be good to choose the loop's surface vector $\hat a$ to point in $+\hat z$ as well to get the right orientation on our loop.

Comment: @Mathematicing,  Note however, that the direction of $\hat a$ is arbitrary, and at the end of the day our result will only differ by a minus sign, and we must physically interpret if current density is entering or leaving the region in question.

Comment: Got it Mr physicists!

Answer (score 1):

It is a somewhat unnatural phrasing of the geometric idea.

The area "vector" is first and foremost an area **bivector** :the bilinear, orientation-sensitive, parallelogram area gadget denoted $v_1 \wedge v_2$, calculable by some determinants, and thought of as a slice of surface area that can be added to other such slices. For surfaces in $3$-dimensional space that bivector can be identified with a vector using the cross product instead, $v_1 \times v_2$, to get a normal vector to the surface of length equal to the oriented area of the parallelogram with sides $v_1, v_2$.

Given a definition of unit length there is a way to standardize area and volume measurements to match that, and unit area is determined in that way. In $3$ dimensions it is the same as the normal vector having length $1$.

Comment: I shall read up more on bivector.